# Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence, $a,b$ given so that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n=a$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n=b$, then $a=b$.

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence. If $a,b$ given so that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}  a_n=a$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n=b$, then $a=b$.

---

Proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}  a_n=a$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n=b$, we can have $\vert a_n-a\vert<\epsilon$ and $\vert a_n-b\vert<\epsilon$.

Then add $\vert a_n-a\vert<\epsilon$ and $\vert a_n-b\vert<\epsilon$, we have 
$$\vert a_n-a\vert+\vert a_n-b\vert<2\epsilon$$ and this is equivalent to $$\vert a_n-a\vert+\vert b-a_n\vert<2\epsilon$$ Applying the triangle inequality, we can have $$\vert (a_n-a)\vert-\vert(b-a_n)\vert\leq\vert (a_n-a)+(b-a_n)\vert\leq\vert a_n-a\vert+\vert b-a_n\vert$$ $$\Longrightarrow\vert (a_n-a)\vert-\vert(b-a_n)\vert\leq\vert b-a\vert\leq\vert a_n-a\vert+\vert b-a_n\vert\tag1$$

so $0\leq\vert b-a\vert$ and  implies $a=b\tag2$

---

From $(1)$ to $(2)$, I am not sure  correct or not. But it seems right to me because the greater equal site can imply $0=\vert b-a\vert$.

Can anyone check my solution? If that is not right, please give me a hit or suggestion to write a better one. (I seen a solution by using contraction)

Comment: Euclid (circa 2500 years ago) : Things equal to the same thing are equal to each other. If f=a and f=b then it does not matter how complicated f is, it's a thing. And the things a,b are equal to the same thing, that is, to f, so a=b.Period.

Comment: @user254665: Why they give proof for this! I cannot understand!

Comment: I suspect this is a school problem to see which  students are even reading the assignment.  I know that some teachers will sometimes include a "free" question, but you won't get the marks for it if you don't  read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very nice start to the proof!  There are some things a little shady with the proof, but the most important point I want to make is this:

When you are writing proofs, you should try to tell the reader a story.  When I read your proof, I feel like you are trying to conform to some type of proof template you have in your mind.  Proofs don't have to follow a specific structure or style -- you can use a lot of words in your proof!  The only thing that **must** be true about your proof is that each step logically follows from the previous one.  With that said, let me tell you how *I* would have written the proof of this -- I am writing this proof off of the top of my head because my goal is just to tell you a story of how I understand each step (that's what a proof should do -- tell the reader how you understand each step).

**Proof**

I want to prove if $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, and $a_{n}$ is a sequence such that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n} = a$ and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n} = b$, then $a = b$.

Well, to show that $a = b$, I can show that $|a - b| = 0$, since if $x$ is a real number, then $|x| = 0$ is equivalent to $x = 0$.  So, I will show that $|a-b| = 0$ (which means I need to start playing around with $|a-b|$ to show this).

But for each natural number $n$, $|a - b| = |a - a_{n} + a_{n} - b| \leq |a - a_{n}| + |a_{n} - b|$ (by the triangle inequality).

But now I know $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n} = a$, so that means for any $\epsilon > 0$, I can find some $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|a - a_{n}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Similarly, since I know $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n} = b$, that means I can $N'$ such that $n \geq N'$ implies $|a_{n} - b| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Then, if I take $M = \max \{N, N'\}$, then if $n \geq M$, we have both $|a_{n} - a| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|b -a_{n}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Since I showed above $|a - b| \leq |a - a_{n}| + |a_{n} - b|$ **for every** $n \in \Bbb N$, that means the inequality is certainly true if $n \geq M$.  But if $n \geq M$, then the inequality implies $|a - b| < \epsilon$.  But $\epsilon$ was arbitrary!  So, since $|a-b| < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$, that means $|a - b| = 0$, so $a = b$.

Comment: I understand that $\epsilon$ is a arbitrary number that we can pick any number, but I don't quite follow that ''since$\vert a-b\vert<0...$ that means$\vert a-b\vert=0$

Comment: @Simple Good question.  I never mentioned the line $|a - b| < 0$ in the proof.  But instead, I am using the fact that if $|a - b| < \epsilon$ for every positive number $\epsilon$, then $|a - b| = 0$.  Why is this?  Well, by the definition of absolute value, $|a-b| \geq 0$, right?  Now, suppose $|a-b| < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$.  Suppose also that $|a - b| \neq 0$.  Then $|a - b| > 0$, right?  But then let $\epsilon ' = \frac{|a-b|}{2}$.  Then $\epsilon '$ is a positive number and $|a - b| \not < \epsilon '$, which contradicts the assumption that $|a - b| < \epsilon$ for every

Comment: @Simple ... $\epsilon > 0$.  So, that means $|a - b|$ must $= 0$ if $|a - b| < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful and clear

Comment: @Simple I am glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon =|a-b|$ and assume for contradiction that $\epsilon>0$.

Then there is some $N, N'$ such that for $n\geq N$ and $n\geq N'$, $|a_n-a|<\epsilon/2$ and $|a_n-b|<\epsilon/2$ respectively. Let $M=\max\{N,N'\}$. Then $|a_M-a|<\epsilon/2$ and $|a_M-b|<\epsilon/2$.

Then applying triangle inequality:

$$|a-b|=|a_M-a-a_M+b|<\epsilon$$

A contradiction, so $|a-b|=0$ and $a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward argument would be to show $|a-b|< \epsilon$ which is given below. I ignored the use of the index for which the sequence converges to $a,b$. We know to just take the max of the two $N_1,N_2$.

$|a_n- a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|a_n-b|< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

$|a-b| = |a-a_n+a_n-b| \leq |a-a_n|+|a_n-b| < \epsilon \Rightarrow a =b$

Answer (score 1):

Careful how you choose your $n$. Remember that the definition says "Given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ then $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon$". A similar index $M$ can be found for $|a_m-b|<\varepsilon$ to be true. Then take the largest of the two. We can assume without loss of generality that $N \geq M$, and in that way you are then safe to say 
$|a_n-b|<\varepsilon$ and $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon$ are simultaneously true for all $n \geq N$.

To streamline the proof, you can actually say $$\vert a_n-a\vert+\vert b-a_n\vert \geq \vert (a_n-a)+(b-a_n)\vert \\ = \vert b-a \vert $$ to see that $$\vert b-a \vert < 2\varepsilon$$ in a few less implications.

Next I can show you a little "trick" to eliminate that $2$ that appears attached to the $\varepsilon$. State that "given $\varepsilon>0$ where $\varepsilon ' = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, I can find indices $N',M'$ (dummy indices to go with $\varepsilon '$) such that $|a_n-a| <  \varepsilon '$ and $|a_m-b| <  \varepsilon '$ for all $n \geq N'$ and for all $m \geq M'$. WLOG take $N'$ to be larger again. Now when you add your inequalities you will just be left with $$\vert b-a \vert < \varepsilon$$ At this point you are done, because the inequality holds for all $n \geq N'$ and an arbitrary $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

"Let ϵ>0. Since lim n→∞an=a and limn→∞an=b, we can have |an−a|<ϵ and |an−b|<ϵ. "

Not quite.  Not for any epsilon and any n.  If for any specific epsilon, this is true *for significantly large* values of n.  Not all n.  In other words for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an N that is sufficiently large so that n > N means n will be sufficiently large for that to be true.

So better writing:

Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Since $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}  a_n=a$ there exists an $N$ such that $n > N$ implies $\vert a_n-a\vert<\epsilon$ and there exists an $M$ such that $n > M$ implies $\vert a_n-b\vert<\epsilon$. So for $n > max(M,N)$:

$\vert a_n-a\vert+\vert a_n-b\vert<2\epsilon$  so

$\vert a - a_n\vert+\vert a_n-b\vert<2\epsilon$

$\vert a - b\vert <= \vert a - a_n\vert+\vert a_n-b\vert<2\epsilon$ (by triangle inequality.)

(From here there are many ways to show a must equal b.  I think a simple contradiction is the clearest.  It lets us practice epsilons.) If $a \ne b$ then $|a - b| > 0$.  If we chose $0< \epsilon < |a - b|/2$ we get a contradictory result.

$|a - b| < 2\epsilon < 2|a -b|/2 = |a - b|$.

This is impossible so |a - b| = 0 and a = b.